# Error: SQL71501: View: XXX.YYYY

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to build Database project in VS3013 with loads of errors:

`SQL71501: View: XXX.YYYY  as an unresolved reference to Schema XXX` and `the object exist in the right schema.`

Please help, how would I resolve it?

Comment: See if this link would help you - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28560.sql-server-data-tools-error-sql71501-unresolved-references-an-obscure-cause.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but in this case - the object  name in DDL is underline with zig- Zag red line and the object it is avalaible in the project.

Comment: CREATE VIEW [XXX].[YYY]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373310/vs-2012-database-project-unresolved-reference-to-object-error