# Visual Studio - Data Connection SQL Server Unresolved Object Reference

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am attempting to connect a Web Forms project to a pre-existing SQL database and have encountered problems. When I open the table definition, it shows errors relating to the foreign keys. This means I am unable to do any updates (such as deleting columns or adding a primary key). If I do, I get an error such as the following:

```
Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.  
Please correct the following errors and try again.

SQL71501 :: Foreign Key: [dbo].[FK937B5F0CACA2B2CE] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[PROPERTY].
SQL71501 :: Foreign Key: [dbo].[FK937B5F0CACA2B2CE] has an unresolved reference to Column [dbo].[PROPERTY].[PROPERTY_ID].
SQL71501 :: Foreign Key: [dbo].[FK937B5F0C84101219] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[PROPERTY_ROOM].
SQL71501 :: Foreign Key: [dbo].[FK937B5F0C84101219] has an unresolved reference to Column [dbo].[PROPERTY_ROOM].[PROPERTY_ROOM_ID].
SQL71501 :: Foreign Key: [dbo].[FK937B5F0C586A8935] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[ITEM_TYPE].
SQL71501 :: Foreign Key: [dbo].[FK937B5F0C586A8935] has an unresolved reference to Column [dbo].[ITEM_TYPE].[ITEM_TYPE_ID].
SQL71501 :: Foreign Key: [dbo].[FK937B5F0CFA31E90A] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[END_USER].
SQL71501 :: Foreign Key: [dbo].[FK937B5F0CFA31E90A] has an unresolved reference to Column [dbo].[END_USER].[END_USER_ID].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
SQL71501 :: Permission has an unresolved reference to object [ticket].
```

This what is in the SQL pane:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TICKET] (
    [TICKET_ID]               NUMERIC (19)   IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PROPERTY_ID]             NUMERIC (19)   NULL,
    [ITEM_TYPE_ID]            NUMERIC (19)   NULL,
    [ITEM_TYPE_DESCRIPTION]   VARCHAR (64)   NULL,
    [SERIAL_NUMBER]           VARCHAR (128)  NULL,
    [LAST_NOTIFICATION_DATE]  DATETIME       NULL,
    [PARTS_USED]              VARCHAR (256)  NULL,
    [ESTIMATED_HOURS]         NUMERIC (4, 2) NULL,
    [ROOM_NUMBER]             VARCHAR (32)   NULL,
    [PROPERTY_ROOM_ID]        NUMERIC (19)   NULL,
    [PREV_MAINT_FLAG]         CHAR (1)       NULL,
    [ASSIGNED_TO_END_USER_ID] NUMERIC (19)   NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK937B5F0CACA2B2CE] FOREIGN KEY ([PROPERTY_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PROPERTY] ([PROPERTY_ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK937B5F0C84101219] FOREIGN KEY ([PROPERTY_ROOM_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PROPERTY_ROOM] ([PROPERTY_ROOM_ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK937B5F0C586A8935] FOREIGN KEY ([ITEM_TYPE_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ITEM_TYPE] ([ITEM_TYPE_ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK937B5F0CFA31E90A] FOREIGN KEY ([ASSIGNED_TO_END_USER_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[END_USER] ([END_USER_ID])
);
```

I read something about adding the master database, so I did add this to my data connections under Server Explorer, but this did not fix it.

I apologize, I am not too familiar with SQL Server, but I have been fighting with this for quite some time and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373310/vs-2012-database-project-unresolved-reference-to-object-error) for answers worked for others

Comment: You haven't write permission. Ask DBA to give you write permisins on tables ticket ,PROPERTY, PROPERTY_ROOM, END_USER